# Slick showing arrows as buttons

Tags: html, slick.js

I am having issue with this slick slider, I expected the arrows to show as in the demo usage, why it is showing up as buttons?

I included in my html

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css.map"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML of your actual buttons? Anyway, I believe you need to remove `.map` from the third url.

Comment: https://codepen.io/swetankrathi/pen/OyRZxL see this example, they are being shown fine here. But in my code they wont. Without the .map they dissapear completely

Answer (score 0):

Slick slider has settings called prevArrow and nextArrow, where you can pass html string, node object or even a jQuery object to replace the default arrow buttons.
Like this:

```
$('.slider-element').slick({
prevArrow: '<a href="#" class="my-arrow-prev">Go to previous slide</a>',
nextArrow: '<a href="#" class="my-arrow-next">Go to next slide</a>',
});
```